# $Pi(n) = Pi(n-2) + x\times [Pi(n-1)]$ for all convergent numerators and denominators. True?

Tags: decimal-expansion, exact-sequence, algorithmic-randomness

Where $x = A001203$, $Pi = A002486$, $A002485$

$Pi(n) = Pi(n-2) + x\times [Pi(n-1)]$ for all $Pi > n+1 $

Hypothesis: This relation evaluates true for all $A002486$ and $A002485$.

Lemma: All "randomness" in $Pi$ decimal expansion is generated by the term "$x$" in the above relation.

See $x =$ https://oeis.org/A001203
See $Pi(n)$ = https://oeis.org/A002485

Per a commenter, an attempt at clarification.

The numerator and denominator convergents for the fractional expansion of pi, as with 22/7, 333/106, 355/113, 103993/33102, where [22, 333, 355, 103993, ...] is part of A002486 and [7, 106, 113, 33102, ...] are part of A002485. Starting with Pi(0) = 333 or 106, Pi(1) =Pi(n-1)+[x*(Pi(n-2)]= 333+(1*22) = 355, where x(n) = [1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 14, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, ...], or A001203 less the first two terms. So, 292*355+333=103993, thus defining the randomness in the decimal expansion as being limited to x (the truncated sequence taken from A001203).

Comment: It would be a lot easier for someone to decide to use time on answering your question if you provided an explanation of what those sequences are _as part of the question_ instead of expecting people to look them up in OEIS before they can even know what the question is about.

Comment: The numerator and denominator convergents for the fractional expansion of pi, as with 22/7, 333/106, 355/113, 103993/33102, where [22, 333, 355, 103993, ...] is part of A002486 and [7, 106, 113, 33102, ...] are part of A002485. Starting with Pi(0) = 333 or 106, Pi(1) = 333(Pi(n-1))+x*[Pi(n-2)]=355, where x(n) = [7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 14, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, ...]

Comment: x @J.W.Helkenberg: This information belongs _in the question_, not in a comment under it. You can (and should) edit the question to make it self-contained.

Comment: I apologize. I have edited the question in an attempt to make the question more intelligible.

Comment: What you've written is essentially the standard relation for a continued fraction convergent (and note that you should have an index '$n$' on $x$ as well, since it's a sequence and not a constant value).  This has nothing to do with $\pi$; it's a matter of definition.

Comment: (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Some_useful_theorems for more on this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the standard recursive rule for continued fractions. If $a = a_0 + 1/(a_1 + 1/(a_2+ \ldots))$ is a continued fraction with coefficients $(a_n)$ and convergents $(p_n/q_n) = a_0 + 1/(a_1+ 1/(a_2+\ldots + 1/a_n))$, then
$$
p_n = a_n p_{n-1} + p_{n-2} \text{ and } q_n = a_n q_{n-1} + q_{n-2}
$$
for all $n \ge 2$. See e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).